# How to get SSRS Date to default correctly?

Tags: function, date, reporting-services

I have been using SSRS for years and have always used the function to set a defualt date parameter for last day of last month using the following.
`=dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))`
However, this time I need to do it for 9 months in the past so with it being the month of March 2021, I want the default date to be 6/30/2020 so I am using:
`=dateadd("m",-8,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))`
SSRS returns the correct year and month but I am getting the date as the 28th of June which I assume is because it is looking at Feb first and then going back 8 months?  If I change the 0 or the 8 to any number I still get 28 in the date field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually subtract the day number from the month to get the first of the month, subtract the number of months plus 1 then subtract a day to get the last day of the previous month. A little tedious but it avoids the various end of month issues.

```
=DATEADD("d", -1, DATEADD("M", 1 - 9, DATEADD("d", 1 - DAY(TODAY), TODAY)))
```

or you can do the same thing with the VB.NET methods:

```
=TODAY.AddDays(1 - TODAY.Day).AddMonths(-8).AddDays(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=DateAdd("d", -1,
        ( 
            DateAdd("m",
                    -8, 
                    DateSerial(YEAR(Today()), Month(Today()),1)
                    )
        )
    )
```

Starting from the inside, the `DateSerial` gets the first day of this month, giving us `2021-03-01` then we subtract 8 months from this giving us `2020-07-01` and then finally subtract 1 day from this to give us the last day of the previous month, `2020-06-30`

Comment: Just noticed Hannover posted an almost identical answer a few mins before me so assuming Hannover's works (it looks fine) then you shoudd probably accept that answer instead of mine.

Comment: Thanks Both!  Both options work! appreciate the help!!